# Convert charset into codepage id

Tags: c#, codepages

While parsing a .RTF file, I run into classic charset identifiers (i.e. 204 = Cyrillic). I'd like to convert them to the appropriate codepage id, so can instantiate the correct `Encoding` object.

There is a nice table on MSDN that lists the available codepages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194829.aspx

Before I copy paste this exact table into my code, is there any way I can make the framework do this for me?